# Websocket-client: WinError 10054 lost closed connection - Why does the Error got raised?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, binance

I am actually trying to run the websocket-client with Python 3.9.2 in PyCharm IDE. But i never get it over a few hours running without getting disconnected. The problem is beyond my current knowledge and i want to solve it :-).
How can i automatically reconnect? Or why do i get disconnected?

I was testing the Websocket without any usage of the incoming data, just to get sure there is no problem with my code executing the incoming data.

You can find the Doc´s for the websocket from binance [here](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#websocket-market-streams).

The following Error is raised.
[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

```
import websocket
from datetime import datetime

websocket.enableTrace(True)
socketurl_combined = "wss://fstream.binance.com/stream?streams=btcusdt_perpetual@continuousKline_1m/btcusdt_perpetual@continuousKline_5m"


def on_message(wsapp, message):
    # print(message)
    pass [..... normaly Code is executed in this function....]


def on_open(wsapp):
    print(f'{str(datetime.now())}   ### ONLINE ###')


def on_close(wsapp):
    print(f'{str(datetime.now())}   ### OFFLINE ###')


def on_error(wsapp, error):
    print(f'{str(error)}   ### OFFLINE ###')


def on_ping(wsapp, message):
    print(f'{str(datetime.now())}   ### Got a Ping! ###')


def on_pong(wsapp, message):
    print(f'{str(datetime.now())}   ### Send a Pong! ###')


wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp(socketurl_combined,
                               on_open=on_open,
                               on_message=on_message,
                               on_error=on_error,
                               on_close=on_close,
                               on_ping=on_ping,
                               on_pong=on_pong)


wsapp.run_forever(ping_interval=60, ping_timeout=30)
```

If it is helpfull, i can post the Tracelog.

For any advice i will be gratefull.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: So you can't wrap the bottom statements in a `while` loop?  And perhaps a `try..except` to capture the error?

Comment: @RufusVS
I haven´t tried yet. At the moment i was focused to get information about the raised WinError 10054 why it shows up.

Comment: I took a quick look at those binance documents, and there were several reasons for the server to disconnect.  One disconnect was automatic at 24 hours.  (I know your disconnect was only a couple hours).  Others were update rate limits, etc.  Are you sure you haven't exceeded any limitations?  (Note:  Your question here asks "How do I reconnect automatically?" not "What is the root cause of this error message?")

Comment: @RufusVS i changed the titel of my topic because meanwhile i know the websocket-client tries to reconnect by it self. I´m not sure, yet, but I could imagine that the host is disconnecting because the traffic is generally too large. I also run the code on my Macbook and got timed out. So i dont think its an issue caused by operatingsystem.